# Pro Tools MIDI setup

Tags: midi, pro-tools, hardware, mac

I would like to get set up to record MIDI through Pro Tools.  I'm hoping I can just connect my MIDI devices to a MIDI interface like this:

[image]

then run it through USB to the Mac, and then be able to access the devices from Pro Tools.
Can someone confirm that this is correct and that I don't have to bring MIDI in through my Pro Tools interface?

Comment: Quick question - how many midi devices?

Comment: @melee: Two that would be permanently attached, but I would also like the ability for clients to bring in their own controllers as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular one will work, no problem, per http://www.motu.com/techsupport/technotes/can-i-use-motu-hardware-in-pro-tools-software

I recommend that unit as well. I've used many, and they have never let me down.

Answer (score 3):

Those MOTU units are brilliant. We have loads of them running everything from HUI from our SSLs to MIDI Keyboard controllers.

You should be able to just select the desired ports in ProTools straight away. If any problems, you can use MIDI STUDIO on your mac os (sorry not sure if you are mac or win user) from within protools and do the setup graphically, fast, intuitively.